# Can't boot FreeBSD 10 after install on UEFI + GPT

Tags: freebsd, uefi, gpt

I have tried to install FreeBSD on Asus G75VW. Setup will partition the disk, install everything.

At reboot I see this:
"Reboot and select proper boot device"
"or Insert Boot Media in selected boot device abd press a key"

So basically it has no idea there is an os. gpart show this as partitions:
freebsd-boot
freebsd-ufs
freebsd-swap

Just to be clear, this is FreeBSD-only setup.
As a test I installed Windows-only and Ubuntu-only setups and they both run well after reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this site,](https://wiki.freebsd.org/UEFI) the EFI boot loader for FreeBSD has yet to be integrated into the FreeBSD binary releases. I haven't checked the status myself, though, so I can't be sure that the information is outdated.

It's not 100% clear from your description if you're doing a FreeBSD-only setup or if you're triple-booting with Windows and Ubuntu. If the latter, that could cause complications, since on a GPT disk, Windows will insist on booting in EFI mode. Switching between BIOS-mode and EFI-mode booting is usually a bit awkward; however, my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) can simplify the task on some (but not all) computers. Basically, you'd install rEFInd and edit `refind.conf`: Uncomment the `scanfor` line and ensure that `hdbios` is among its options. This will enable rEFInd to chain from a standard EFI-mode boot into the BIOS-mode FreeBSD boot loader.

Although using rEFInd in this way might work if you've got a FreeBSD-only system, a simpler solution may work: Using a GPT-unaware partitioning tool, set the "boot flag" (aka the "active flag") on the MBR's type-0xEE protective partition. Some EFIs refuse to start an OS in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode unless an MBR partition is marked as active, and this workaround will satisfy such EFIs. See [my Web page on this topic](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html) for more information and some other suggestions, should this solution fail.

Comment: This is a FreeBSD-only setup , I will correct the question

Comment: I will try what you suggest. A subquestion in this case - how can I boot the installed freebsd so I can install the boot manager ? From live/install CD how do I do that ?

Comment: If you've done a complete install, the FreeBSD boot loader should already be present on the hard disk. If so, setting the boot/active flag on the MBR's 0xEE protective partition will *probably* get the hard disk booting. You can use an emergency boot disk to adjust the partition table. Any but the latest versions of Linux's `fdisk` should do the trick. I'm not sure about FreeBSD tools, offhand.

Comment: I'm trying to triple-boot with windows/linux/freebsd... and while I actually load freebsd by using legacy bios. I tried with your suggestion: `scanfor internal,external,optical,manual,hdbios` on `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind.conf`, but still nothing happens :c